# C typedef of pointer to structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I had come across the following code:

```
typedef struct {
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
} *vector;
```

**Is this a valid type definition?** The code compiles and runs fine. I was just curious if this is common practice.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Absolutely valid.
Usually, you can take full advantage of this way by defining two types together:

```
typedef struct
{
 int a;
 int b;
} S1, *S1PTR;
```

Where S1 is a struct and S1PTR is the pointer to this struct.

Comment: ...and maybe `const *S1CPTR`.

Comment: Just to confirm I understand. Is that equivalent to `typedef struct {...} S1; typedef S1* S1PTR;`?

Answer (score 30):

Yes it is. But it is in my opininon bad style. Not the direct declaration of the struct, but the direct declaration of a pointer type. It is obfuscation, the information that a given variable or parameter is a pointer (and to a lesser extent for arrays) is extremely important when you want to read code.

When reviewing code it is often difficult to see at first glance which function could have a side effect or not. If the types used hide this information, it adds a memorisation burden to the reader.

```
int do_fancy(vector a, vector b);
```

or

```
int do_fancy(vector *a, vector *b);
```

in the first case I can miss easily that that function may change the content of a or b. In the second I'm warned.

And when actually writing code I also know directly to write `a->x` and not have the compiler tell me `error: request for member` x' in something not a structure or union`.

I know, it looks like a personal taste thing, but having worked with a lot of external code, I can assure you that it's extremely annoying when you do not recognize the indirection level of variables. That's one reason I also dislike C++ references
(in Java it's not because all objects are passed by reference, it's consistent) and Microsoft's `LPCSTR` kind of types.

Comment: +1 for the observation that `typedef struct { ... } *obj` leads to a type that mysteriously requires `->` instead of `.` for element access.

Comment: Strict naming conventions would inform user of the type of typedef, so not really bad style. However I see your point when working with external code using different coding practises,

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is valid. If you need more "security" you can also do

```
typedef struct vector_{
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
} *vector;
```

then you can use both

```
struct vector_ *var;
vector var;
```

But don't forget the ending semi-colon.

Using only typedef means that you name it that way. otherwise it'd be more or less anonymous.

Comment: I believe you can use the same name for both (i.e., you don't need the underscore but can leave everything else in your code the same, because the namespaces are separate).

Answer (score 4):

It a valid one, what it does is it defines a new type. As @Alex said, it would be useful to define a type and pointer type.

You could create more pointers just by using

```
S1PTR ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, ...;
```

instead of

```
S1 *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3, ...;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is valid as described in above answers. A small suggestion, it would be better if you provide a tag name too, as follows. This would help some IDEs to better parse your code.

```
typedef struct vactor_tag {
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
} *vector;
```

Answer (score -1):

yes...saves you the trouble of constantly typing the word 'struct' everytime you declare the vector struct or a pointer to it.

Comment: I think the question had to do more with the typedef'ing to *vector rather than just vector.