# creating Typedef pointers to Typedef structs in C

Tags: c, typedef

Have a question about `typedef` in C.

I have defined struct:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *nextptr;
} nodes;
```

How would I create `typedef` pointers to `struct` Node ??

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C typedef of pointer to structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543713/c-typedef-of-pointer-to-structure)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can typedef them at the same time:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *nextptr;
} node, *node_ptr;
```

This is arguably hard to understand, but it has a lot to do with why C's declaration syntax works the way it does (i.e. why `int* foo, bar;` declares `bar` to be an int rather than an `int*`

Or you can build on your existing typedef:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *nextptr;
} node;

typedef node* node_ptr;
```

Or you can do it from scratch, the same way that you'd typedef anything else:

```
typedef struct Node* node_ptr;
```

Answer (score 4):

To my taste, the easiest and clearest way is to do forward declarations of the `struct` and `typedef` to the `struct` and the pointer:

```
typedef struct node node;
typedef node * node_ptr;
struct node {
    int data;
    node_ptr nextptr;
};
```

Though I'd say that I don't like pointer `typedef` too much.

Using the same name as `typedef` and `struct` tag in the forward declaration make things clearer and eases the API compability with C++.

Also you should be clearer with the names of your types, of whether or not they represent one node or a set of nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Like so:

```
typedef nodes * your_type;
```

Or:

```
typedef struct Node * your_type;
```

But I would prefer the first since you already defined a type for `struct Node`.