# Struct basics (struct as pointer)

Tags: c

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    typedef struct
    {
        int *u;
        struct node next;
    } *node;

    int main()
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

What is meant by `*node` here? I don't get it. I think there should be a node here but it is compiling anyway.

Comment: The `homework` tag is deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: @KirilKirov since like a month ago. You've missed the message on the right side. There's been some effort to clean up questions with this tag.

Comment: @KirilKirov: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: Wow, 3 answers within 14 seconds :) Thanks, I've missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `typedef` defines a new type, `node`, which is a pointer to the structure.

The code in the question may not compile since `struct node` doesn't appear to be defined anywhere and yet it's used inside of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Compare this:

```
typedef int * pointer_to_int;
```

Here, the asterisk is part of the type being given a new name, i.e. `pointer_to_int` is an alias for the type `int *`.

With your example, it's exactly the same! The asterisk is part of the type, so that `node` becomes an alias for the type `pointer to struct node { int *u; struct node *next; }`.

Also, note that it's often a bad idea to include the asterisk in `typedef`, since it makes the code much harder to use. In C, it's often very interesting to know whether a variable is a pointer or not, so hiding that fact isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The correct definition is:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int *u;
    struct Node *next;
} *node;
```

In your code there is a problem in a struct declaration; syntax is:

```
struct identifier/tag {struct declaration list}
```

struct declaration list is a sequence of declarations for the members of the structure;

typedef declaration provides a way to create an alias, a synonym for the type; syntax is:

```
typedef type alias
```

Where is the Error?

```
typedef struct {
```

In this case there isn't an alias!

Comment: Any elaboration on what you did and why?

Comment: @Surai Menon Maybe you are interested into a: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481603/creating-typedef-pointers-to-typedef-structs-in-c

Comment: I'm not asking to explain it for myself. It's just to the OP your answer may not be very helpful.

Comment: it is simply the correct construction of node, what is the problem about that? I don't understand what do you want!

Comment: I'm only pointing out that the answer is incomplete and possibly unclear to the OP.

Comment: I added some info, thanks for the advice. I hope that is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

problems here:

```
typedef struct
    {
        int *u;
        struct node next; //struct node is NOT defined.
    } *node;
```

This is wrong:

it should be :

```
typedef struct node{
   int *u;
   struct node *next;
}*nodeptr;
```

This code means that "nodeptr" is a pointer to `struct node;`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've never seen this kind of declaration. This use to be something like:

```
typedef struct {
  int *u;
  struct node *next;
} node;
```

And that's simple: you are defining a structure with a pointer to an integer and a pointer to another element of the same structure.

Comment: In your code, the `struct` is anonymous. Thus field `next` is not a pointer to a similar `struct` but to an undefined `struct node`. The  `typedef` has nothing to do with the name of the `struct` itself (`typedef struct { ... } name` is more or less equivalent to `struct __anonymous__ { ... }; typedef struct __anonymous__ name`)