# Pointer on a struct in C

Tags: c

```
typedef struct st {
    double d ;
    struct st *n ;
} st, *List ;
```

On this part:

```
} st, *List ;
```

What is this second "st"? Is it an object created (why does it have the same name as the type)? I don't understand the "*List". Does it use typedef to say that a "List" is a pointer to an "st"?
Thank you.

Comment: It take me less than one minute to figure out your answer because this question is a double with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543713/c-typedef-of-pointer-to-structure. Next time, consider searching one google before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part

```
typedef struct st {...} st;
```

creates a new symbol `st` that can be used to declare instances of `struct st` without the keyword `struct`. You can read [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef) for more information - it has some examples.

The second declaration `*List` creates a pointer type to `struct st` so you can declare a pointer to the structure without having to write `struct st*`.

`typedef` essentially creates an alias that can be used in place of the original type.

Answer (score 2):

The first `st` is part of `struct st` and creates a named struct. The second `st` is part of `typedef … st` and creates a type as an alias for `struct st`. The `* List` creates a type `List` as a pointer to `struct st`.

Answer (score 2):

`typedef` lets you define multiple type aliases. For example, you can do this:

```
typedef int Number, *NumberPtr;
```

This defines `Number` to be an alias for `int`, and `NumberPtr` to be an alias for `int*`.

Your declaration does the same, except it uses `struct st` instead of an `int`. In other words, it defines two type names - `st` for the `struct st`, and `List` for `struct st*`.

This lets you write

```
st s;
List p;
```

instead of

```
struct st s;
struct st *p;
```

Answer (score 1):

This does three things: The first is it defines a struct called `struct st` that contains a double and a pointer to another `struct st`. This first task could be accomplished on its own like so:

```
struct st {
    double d ;
    struct st *n ;
};
```

The `typedef` is doing two more things. It is defining `st` to be `struct st` and also defining `List` to be `struct st *`. A more simple example of this 2x `typedef` is something like:

```
typedef int Integer, *PointerToInteger;
```