# C syntax about typedef struct pointer, explanation needed

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, struct, typedef

```
typedef struct person *person_t;
```

In this case, what is person_t exactly? is it a pointer to person or person?
In C++, if I were to declare a ptr to an object, I would do:

```
person* p;
```

In this case, does it mean I can just write:

```
person_t p?
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's a poor `typedef`. You should use `typedef struct person person_t;`. For a pointer type, you should use something along the lines of `typedef struct person* person_ptr;`.

Answer (score 2):

`person_t` is `struct person *`

So you can just have

```
person_t p;
```

When you do

```
typedef struct person *person_t;
person_t p;
```

`p` is a pointer to structure `struct person`

Else if you have

```
typedef struct person person_t;
```

Then

```
person_t *p;
```

will give you a pointer to your structure which is `p`

**PS:** ***I would always go by the latter one which I feel is more readable and less confusing. (Purely IMO)***

Answer (score 0):

It is act like pointer to a structure.

```
 struct person *p; // is equivalent to person_t p;
```

Because you are type casting the pointer also.

```
 person_t p; // it  will act like a pointer to  structure.
```

You can refer this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543713/c-typedef-of-pointer-to-structure)

Answer (score 0):

This declaration

```
typedef struct person *person_t;
```

introduces alias `person_t` for type `struct person *`. So you can use either `person_t` or `struct person *` interchangeably. For example these two declarations are equivalent

```
struct person *p1;
person_t *p2;
```

The problem is that using identifier `person_t` for denoting pointer of type `struct person *` is not a good choice. The reader of the code can think that `person_t` is an alias for the structure person itself. It would be better for example to declare the alias of the pointer like `person_ptr`  or something else that it would be seen that this type denotes a pointer.

Comment: Wait, the part that confuses me the most is whether to use person_t *p2, or person_t p2, do we still keep the star?

Comment: @ohshire  You defined in the typedef person_t like struct person *. So they are interchangeable. If you will write person_t * then it will be equivalent to struct person ** that is it will be pointer to pointer.