# Is this typedef-ing a function in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, alias, typedef

This is a block of sample C++ code. I read the definitions of typedef, struct, enum and union but I still can't decipher this.

```
typedef NTSTATUS (WINAPI * PFN_NTQUERYINFORMATIONFILE)(
    IN HANDLE FileHandle,
    OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    OUT PVOID FileInformation,
    IN ULONG Length,
    IN FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass
);
```

1. Is NTSTATUS (WINAPI * PFN_NTQUERYINFORMATIONFILE) a function? Why does the parameter mean by having a * in between?
2. IN HANDLE FileHandle, OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock.. What does the IN/OUT mean?
3. Why isn't there a new alias?
4. Can I declare a new alias name and a pointer alias name? In the example below, would I use PFILE_NAME_INFORMATION for the pointer name and FILE_NAME_INFORMATION otherwise?

   ```
   typedef struct _FILE_NAME_INFORMATION { ... } 
   FILE_NAME_INFORMATION, *PFILE_NAME_INFORMATION;
   ```

Comment: additional whitespace, macros, ... do you have an IDE?

Comment: First let me say `_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION` is a reserved identifier: You can't legally use it. Second, `IN` and `OUT` are not C++ keywords so I'm *guessing* they're just `#define`s to nothing and used only as annotation.

Comment: In your last question, 4., are you really asking about `struct`s or is this just an analogy and you're actually asking about function pointers?

Answer (score 1):

This typedef declaration

```
typedef NTSTATUS (WINAPI * PFN_NTQUERYINFORMATIONFILE)(
    IN HANDLE FileHandle,
    OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    OUT PVOID FileInformation,
    IN ULONG Length,
    IN FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass
);
```

introduces an `alias named`PFN_NTQUERYINFORMATIONFILE` for the type

```
NTSTATUS (WINAPI * )(
    IN HANDLE FileHandle,
    OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
    OUT PVOID FileInformation,
    IN ULONG Length,
    IN FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass
);
```

that represents a pointer to function with 5 parameters and the return type `NTSTATUS`.

Now you may use this name to declare pointers to functions of such a type

```
PFN_NTQUERYINFORMATIONFILE ptr;
```

You could get the same the following way that looks more clear

```
using PFN_NTQUERYINFORMATIONFILE =  
    NTSTATUS (WINAPI * )(
        IN HANDLE FileHandle,
        OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock,
        OUT PVOID FileInformation,
        IN ULONG Length,
        IN FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass
    );
```

Also consider the following simple example

```
#include <iostream>

int sum( int x, int y )
{
    return x + y;
}

int product( int x, int y )
{
    return x * y;
}

int division( int x, int y )
{
    return x / y;
}

typedef int ( *fp )( int, int );

int main( )
{
    for ( fp f : { sum, product, division } ) std::cout << f( 10, 2 ) << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
12
20
5
```

Take into account that function names implicitly are converted to pointers to functions when they are used in expressions.

So for example this statement with the function from the above demonstrative program is valid

```
std::cout << ( ***/* replace the comment with as many asterisks as you like */****sum )( 10, 20 ) << std::endl;
```

So if you are paid accordingly to the number of typed symbols in the program then you can use this trick with function calls.

```
(****************************************************sum )( 10, 20 );
```

This is restricted only by the compiler limits.

As for `IN` and `OUT` then they are macros used by Microsoft to make it clear what each parameter of a function is used for, whether it provides an input value or it serves as an output parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is a type alias for a function pointer.

> Is NTSTATUS (WINAPI * PFN_NTQUERYINFORMATIONFILE) a function? Why does the parameter mean by having a * in between?

No, this is only part of the type. `*` denotes a pointer. This is a pointer to a function with a `WINAPI` (`__stdcall`) calling convention, an `NTSTATUS` return value, and several parameters (`HANDLE`, `PIO_STATUS_BLOCK`, `PVOID`, `ULONG`, and `FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS`).

> IN HANDLE FileHandle, OUT PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock.. What does the IN/OUT mean?

Those are annotations. IN means that the function uses the parameter for input only and OUT means the function uses the parameter for output only (it writes to what the parameter points to). INOUT would mean the function reads from and writes to what is being pointed to.

Neil MacIntosh actually gave a couple of presentations on static analysis at CppCon this year, where he talked about how such annotations came to be in the Microsoft codebase and how they help to improve static analysis tools' capabilities without requiring more resources. However, you can provide the same help with actual types instead of annotations that get compiled into nothing, and this is the approach that the CppCoreGuidelines project with the GSL is taking.

> Why isn't there a new alias?

There is. It's `PFN_NTQUERYINFORMATIONFILE`. This is just a quirk of the C declaration syntax, which, for the most part, reads from the inside outward rather than left to right.

> Can I declare a new alias name and a pointer alias name?

Not that I know of, no. Had you done the same trick with `typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI func)(...), *func_pointer;`, `func_pointer` would be a `NTSTATUS*` while `func` is the same as in the question, but not a pointer.

This certainly works for other type aliases produced through `typedef`, though, such as the `struct` example in the question, which does indeed declare `FILE_NAME_INFORMATION` as a `struct _FILE_NAME_INFORMATION` and `PFILE_NAME_INFORMATION` as a `struct _FILE_NAME_INFORMATION*`, the `struct` being there to emphasize the different kinds of names being declared.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, it's a function pointer. The asterisk in between is just part of the normal syntax for a function pointer - the `WINAPI` [is just a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348442/what-does-winapi-in-main-function-mean).
2. Macros too. `IN` indicates an argument read by the function (like a const reference or a copied-by-value argument) while `OUT` refers to an argument used to "return" an argument (like a non-const reference).
3. There is one: `PFN_NTQUERYINFORMATIONFILE`.
4. [Yes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543713/c-typedef-of-pointer-to-structure)

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking about with #4. I believe the question is whether there's a way to declare both an alias for a function type and an alias for a pointer to that same function type in a single statement, just like how you can with other type aliases, such as structures.

Comment: @chris So you mean it's just an analogy? May be but I don't see any hint indicating that. The "In the example below [...]" convinces me.

Comment: This was my interpretation of the question. The OP can certainly clarify.