# How to access/modify variable inside struct with a pointer to struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct vector_{
    int x;
    double y;
    double z;
} *vector;

void modi(vector a);

int main() {
  vector var;
  var->x = 2;
  modi(var);
  return 0;
}

void modi(vector a){
  printf("avant modif %d",a->x);
  a->x = 5;
  printf("avant modif %d",a->x);
}
```

I tried to run it but I got a segmentation fault.

The problem is simple: the access/modify with a struct pointer variable.

I look on Stack Overflow but I got an incomplete answer for my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1544134

What is the right way to access/modify in this case (a `struct` pointer variable)?

Comment: `vector var = malloc(sizeof(vector));`   You must allocate space if you're going to do it this way...

Comment: Maybe if you didn't try to hide indirection behind your typedef you wouldn't confuse yourself?

Comment: @Kevin `vector var = malloc(sizeof(*var));`

Comment: You never allocated any space for the pointer to point at; you invoke undefined behaviour when you dereference the uninitialized pointer.  And, in general, don't hide pointers behind typedefs.

Comment: @EOF I see that hide indirection was more securized than the standard way. It was the reason I will use it.

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) for the low-down.  There are circumstances when it is OK to do so — pointers to functions and (possibly) pointers to opaque types are examples.  However, if you need to dereference the data in the type, it is best to avoid typedefing the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this, it works, I expanded a bit. Please read the comments in the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct vector_
{
  int x;
  double y;
  double z;
};

typedef struct vector_ *vector;
void modi( vector a );

int main(  )
{
  struct vector_ av;    // we have a structure av
  vector var = &av;     // pointer var points to av
  var->x = 2;

  printf( "\ndans main() avant call to modi() %d", var->x );

  modi( var );

  printf( "\ndans main() apres call to modi() %d", var->x );
  return 0;
}

void modi( vector a )
{
  printf( "\ndans modi() avant modif %d", a->x );
  a->x = 5;
  printf( "\ndans modi() apres modif %d", a->x );
}
```