# typedef struct pointer into JNA

Tags: java, c++, pointers, struct, jna

I am working on JNA for my application and I am confused about using **typedef struct pointer** in java.
Please check my code and guide me.
Thank you in advance!

**Below is my c++ code**

```
typedef struct tagHWDeviceInfo
{
USHORT          VendorID;      // vendor id
USHORT          ProductID;     // product id
DWORD           nXExt;         // firmware width
DWORD           nYExt;         // firmware height
DWORD           preesure;      // pressure level
DWORD           penState;      // pen state
}HWDeviceInfo, *PHWDeviceInfo;
```

**and java code**

```
public class HWDeviceInfo extends Structure{
    short VendorID;
    short ProductID;
    int   nXExt;        // firmware width
    int   nYExt;        // firmware height
    int   preesure;     // pressure level
    int   penState;
}
```

**Now my question is:** what does it mean by `*PHWDeviceInfo` in c++ code and how can I use this pointer in my java code?

Comment: You might want to [read this about pointers/references](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/141838).

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? It's a pointer. See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543713/c-typedef-of-pointer-to-structure

Comment: And you can't really use pointers in Java code. What could you do with it?

Comment: have you worked with the JNA before? we can use Pointer class with the jna.jar.
I know we cannot use pointer in java but please understand my question.

Comment: @СӏаџԁеМаятіи see this article [JNA Overview](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html)

Comment: What's there to see? You ask how you could use a pointer in Java. The answer is: you can't. And I want to know why you think you could do anything with a pointer in Java. You can load that data into a java object of type HWDeviceInfo. And you can use points to structs in your C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNA automatically converts instances of `Structure` to `struct *` in function calls, and to `struct` in structure field definitions.  `Structure.getPointer()` gives you the pointer that JNA will use.

You can modify this default behavior by tagging your class and/or parameter types with the `Structure.ByReference` and `Structure.ByValue` interfaces.

JNA [documents this clearly](https://jna.java.net/javadoc/overview-summary.html#structures) as noted by @areeba-irfan-ullah-khan.