# How to wrap C++ structs that have multiple types for C#?

Tags: c#, c++, struct, marshalling, wrapper

I'm trying to wrap a set of C++ functions and structs based on a header file. So far I think I understand the concepts behind wrapping each structure, but I'm not sure how to pull this one apart:

```
typedef struct
{
    BYTE    commCode;
    *other stuff*

    struct
    {
        DWORD   size;
        LPBYTE  payload;
    }
    Data;    
}
Set, *CommSet;
```

Should I do something like this?:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class Set
{
    public byte commCode;

    public class DATA
    {
        public uint size;
        public byte[] payload;
    }
}
```

But at this point I'm not sure how to account for the other type, the `*CommSet` pointer. Do I need a separate structure/class for that?

Comment: What is `CommSet`?

Comment: Off topic: `typedef struct` is generally not required in C++. `struct Set` would be sufficient for `Set` to be a valid identifier. `using CommSet = Set *;` will provide `CommSet`.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply shorthand notation for declaring both the `typedef struct` and a pointer to it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1543720/802203).

In your PInvoke bindings, depending on how it's used, you can use an IntPtr and marshal structs of type `Set` as required, or use [MarshalAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to marshal a pointer pointing to a known length of structures.