# c free() causes crash, but the data itself works normally and is the correct size

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures, malloc, free

My program crashes every time when I try to free one of the strings in my struct, here are the functions I call and the struct:

```
typedef struct course
{
    char *id;
    char *name;
    double credits;
    DynamicArray preCourses;
} *Course;


Course c2;
createCourse("345682", "Cyberpunk and the Future", 3, &c2);
destroyCourse(c2);
```

Here is the code for the creation function:

```
CourseResult createCourse(char *id, char *name, double credits, Course *course)
{
    assert(name != NULL || id != NULL);
    Course temp= malloc(sizeof(Course));
    if(temp == NULL)
        return COURSE_ILLEGAL_PARAMETER;
    temp->id = (char *)malloc((strlen(id)+1));
    if (temp->id == NULL) {
        free(temp);
        return COURSE_MEMORY_ERROR;
    }
    temp->name = (char *)malloc((strlen(name)+1));
    if (temp->name == NULL) {
        free(temp->id);
        free(temp);
        return COURSE_MEMORY_ERROR;
    }
    temp->preCourses=createDynamicArray();
    if(temp->preCourses == NULL){
        free(temp->name);
        free(temp->id);
        free(temp);
        return COURSE_MEMORY_ERROR;
    }
    strcpy(temp->id,id);
    strcpy(temp->name,name);
    temp->credits=credits;
    *course = temp;
    return COURSE_OK;
}
```

The free function:

```
void destroyCourse(Course course1)
{
    destroyDynamicArray(course1->preCourses);
    printf("%s", course1->id); //prints 345682
    printf("%d", strlen(course1->id)); //prints 6
    free(course1->id); //crashes here
    free(course1->name);
    free(course1);
}
```

The string itself is located in the memory, and is the right length.
Thanks for any and all of the help!

Comment: Minor help - calling free passing in a NULL is a defined behavior so you could have a common "failed alloc, free all" area if you wanted.

Comment: Another thought - if you have written passed the end of any of your strings, this will likely corrupt the dynamic memory's internal data and cause a crash.  Double check bounds on your strings in memory before freeing.

Comment: Could the (not presented) functions create/destroyDynamicArray corrupt your heap? Does it work when you comment these calls out?

Comment: Seems to work correctly https://onlinegdb.com/rkaQwO3lf

Comment: Another victim of those popular bad habits: 1) typedef-ing "innocent" type names that hide pointers inside - `Course` in this case, 2) using `sizef(type)` under `malloc` - `malloc(sizeof(Course))` instead of the proper `malloc(sizeof *temp)`.

Comment: It is valid to `typedef` a pointer, but is not always considered good practice, as this answer to [C typedef of pointer to structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8853708/4142924) says. Although a pointer `typedef` can make the code syntax easier to write, without having to know where parentheses should be used, it may not be so easy to follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Course temp= malloc(sizeof(Course));
```

`Course` is typedefed as a pointer, you need to reserve space for the whole `struct`, not for a pointer to it, change to:

```
Course temp = malloc(sizeof(struct course));
```

or better yet

```
Course temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
```

Comment: Welp you just saved my project and hours of heartache. THANK YOU!