# strange struct and typedef definition

Tags: c, gcc, struct

I came across this struct declaration and I do not now what is the last pointer doing here?

```
typedef const struct
{
   //Ommiting the members for stackoverflow!!!

} PWMnCurrFdbkParams_t, *pPWMnCurrFdbkParams_t;
```

So the question is

- what is the effect of `,` here?
- what is type   of`*pPWMnCurrFdbkParams_t`
- what usecase there is to it?

Comment: Have a look at: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543713/c-typedef-of-pointer-to-structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543713/c-typedef-of-pointer-to-structure) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite common, for example Microsoft use it a lot in their header files.

There are two types (comma separated) defined here, `PWMnCurrFdbkParams_t` is of type `const struct` and `pPWMnCurrFdbkParams_t` is a pointer to that `const struct`.

The `*` is not part of the name, just as `int *x` is where `x` is a pointer to an `int`.

Use case is almost any collection of structures, like a linked list or tree.